# Talking to an Authentication Server

Tags: python, authentication, rest

I'm building my startup and I'm thinking ahead for shared use of services.

So far I want to allow people who have a user account on one app to be able to use the same user account on another app. This means I will have to build an authentication server.

I would like some opinions on how to allow an app to talk to the authentication server. Should I use curl? Should I use Python's http libs? All the code will be in Python.

All it's going to do is ask the authentication server if the person is allowed to use that app and the auth server will return a JSON user object. All authorization (roles and resources) will be app independent, so this app will not have to handle that.

Sorry if this seems a bit newbish; this is the first time I have separated authentication from the actual application.

Comment: I think this question needs some clarification.  Is the central server to be used for identifying the user (authentication) or for reporting which resources the user is allowed to access (authorization) or both?  The difference might be relevant when considering existing technologies to suggest, e.g. RADIUS or OpenID.

Comment: @Forest I stated in my post that this is purely authentication and not authorization.

Comment: Yes, but you also said you plan to "ask the authentication server if the person is allowed to use that app", which is an authorization issue, not authentication.  It left me confused.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you plan to write your own auth client code, it isn't event-driven, and you don't need to validate an https certificate, I would suggest using python's built-in urllib2 to call the auth server.  This will minimize dependencies, which ought to make deployment and upgrades easier.

That being said, there are more than a few existing auth-related protocols and libraries in the world, some of which might save you some time and security worries over writing code from scratch.  For example, if you make your auth server speak OpenID, many off-the-self applications and servers (including Apache) will have auth client plugins already made for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really a programming problem so much as it is an architecture problem.  What I would recommend for your specific situation is to setup an LDAP server for authentication, authorization, and accounting (AAA).  Then have your applications use that (every language has modules and libraries for LDAP).  It is a reliable, secure, proven, and well-known way of handling such things.

Even if you strictly want to enforce HTTP-based authentication it is easy enough to slap an authentication server in front of your LDAP and call it a day.  There's even existing code to do just that so you won't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: What other service would I use for an architecture problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is also [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) that you might wont to look at,